# How to login with native app using custom button instead native LoginButton in Xamarin Android

Tags: facebook, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm implementing social login in my app, I have created a layout, It has a button call `Facebook Signup` design my self. Now, I want to use its button click to get login from native installed app instead `FacebookSDK` `LoginButton` functionality.

default login button:

//I want to make it working

```
var myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.Click += myButton_Click;
```

//Not the below one

```
var loginButton = new LoginButton(Context);
loginButton.SetReadPermissions("myScope");
var facebookCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
    {
        HandleSuccess = (LoginResult loginResult) =>
        {
            formsButton.LoginSuccess(loginResult.AccessToken.Token);
        },

        HandleCancel = () =>
        {
            // App code
        },

        HandleError = (FacebookException exception) =>
        {
            // App code
        }
    };
loginButton.RegisterCallback(activity.CallbackManager, facebookCallback);
myLayout.AddView(loginButton);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following code it might help you:

```
var YourButton = new Button(this);
YourButton.Click += (object sender, EventArgs ev) => 
{
    if (loginManager != null)
           loginManager.LogInWithReadPermissions (this, new string[]{"yourScope"});
};

yourLayout.AddView(YourButton);
```